# Are there any way to change attribute set using CSV in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, attribute-set

I have added product using default attribute set now I want to change the attribute set, so I have create a csv using sku and new attribute set but it didn't work.

This is my csv file format,

```
sku     attribute_set_code
1110086 Cleaning
1126000 Consumables
1127841 Cleaning
1127844 Cleaning
1127845 Cleaning
```

I have updated and result is successfully  imported but it didn't change the product attribute sets. 
can any one look this
thanks.

Comment: What's magento2 version?

Comment: @Chandra Kumar - Magento 2.1.7

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5498

Comment: @Chandra Kumar - Im using magento 2 cloud , I have find lot of magento cloud bugs.